# C# Decrypt symmetric key with private asymmetric key

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

We received a Encrypted XML document where some content was encrypted with a symmetric key and the symmetric key was supplied in the XML, encrypted with the public key of our certificate.
I tried to decrypt the latter part with our private key but it keeps throwing an error

This is my code, help is much appreciated

```
public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, RSA privateKey, string KeyName)
{
      XmlElement xmlelement = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("bla")[0] as XmlElement;
      EncryptedKey encryptedKey = new EncryptedKey();
      encryptedKey.LoadXml(xmlelement);

       //How is the privateKey mapped to encryptedKey??
       //DecryptEncryptedKey throws a value null exception

       EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(Doc); 
       byte[] decrOut = exml.DecryptEncryptedKey(encryptedKey);            
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code that encrypted it?

Comment: No, the XML is generated by a third party

Comment: Do you know which encryption algorithm was used for the symmetric part and for the key?

Comment: symmetric key was chosen by the supplier. Used the key for aes256-cbc-pkc5 on the xml elements. symmetric key was then encrypted with public part of our certificate (2048)

Answer (score 0):

you must have XmlDocument and certificated pre loaded i.e

XmlDocument doc object with your xml
X509Certificate2 x509ServiceProvider (your certificate with private key)

```
        // Go and get the encrypted key node
        XmlElement encryptedCipherValueElement = (XmlElement)doc.SelectSingleNode("/XPATH to CipherValue i.e. encrypted symmetric key");

        // These are the input bytes to be decrypted
        byte[] encryptedCipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedCipherValueElement.InnerText);

        // The RSA service provider is necessary as we can't just rely on IIS to decrypt stuff
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaServiceProvider = x509ServiceProvider.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        // We want to use PKCS1 v1.5 padding which corresponds to OEAP padding being false 
        // This is what other vendors appear to be using. This may become a parameter
        // in time
        const bool OeapPadding = false;
        byte[] decryptedCipherBytes = rsaServiceProvider.Decrypt(encryptedCipherBytes, OeapPadding);

        // We want to wipe out any lingering references to keys or algorithms as
        // soon as possible
        rsaServiceProvider.Clear();

        return decryptedCipherBytes;
```